SSD Multi-Boot Grub Trouble
I have 3 Linux-Distros installed on a SSD (Ubuntu, Parrot, Kali). There are all separated from each other, meaning they don't share a /home partition or anything like that. I also have no swap partitions.
I had this idea of a portable drive (in my case a SSD) containing a couple of distros that I could carry around and simply plug into any computer and start working from there. The grub used for this SSD is managed from Ubuntu.
Now the problem I have is that all the computers with whom I worked so fare also had other  SSD's plugged into them as well. So the existing Grub entries were invalid every time I switched devices, because sometimes my SSD was mounted to /dev/sda/, sometimes to /dev/sdb/ etc. The only entry that was always working was of course the Ubuntu one. Additionally, most of the time when this happened I could still select on the other boot entries, but then I would be prompted to the initramfs rescue console, informing me that my memory was corrupt somwhow. I would then fix the issue by executing blkid <uuid> -y and the I would be able to boot into the OS. Obviously my memory was neither corrupt nor would this fix the problem as it again wont let me boot into it using another device without doing that initramfs console thing.
My question now is, is it possible to create like "permanent" grub entries that work regardless on where the SSD is mounted on? For example using uuid's that - as far as I know - always should stay the same.

(I even tried  to install a grub for each linux distro separately so I could go into boot-options and simply select the grub from each one. But despite of those EFI files existing on the EFI partition, my primary computer doesn't recognize them (except Ubuntu). However my second computer does. Maybe because the second one created them? I don't know and I am certain that there is a better solution to this than having n grubs installed at one place.)

UEFI entries are normally forgotten when a drive is removed. You have to directly boot from UEFI boot menu entry which will be /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Or only one system will be default. Rest you have to boot from grub. I have Multiple installs on external SSD and sometimes just have to use e and edit grub entry from hd1 to hd0 or vice versa. I also try to use labels which sometimes work. Using 40_custom & Custom menu
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive

+1 to your profile.  I like the Python reference. See: How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator).  Note that the OS here is irrelevant.  It's the concept that matters, i.e., use the vm with the portable disk connected as the fake HDD, and you'll end up with a not fake grub install directly on your portable disk

Do you mean like you have manually written entries for the non-Ubuntu installations? If you need a portable setup, you'll need to use uuid everywhere (i.e., use search -u $some_uuid -s instead of set root=(x,y) in grub entries, root=UUID=$some_other_uuid in the linux lines of the entries, and fstab entries in each installation, and maybe some more in certain cases).

I even tried to install a grub for each linux distro For the portable scenario, you can't rely on the UEFI boot menu to choose which grub to boot. (Some UEFI implementations does support multiple ESP per drive though.) However, you can probably have entries in the "main" grub that chainloads other grubs with chainloader path/to/some/dot/efi.

After reading through some of the comments I was finally able to resolve the issue. As suggested by @oldfred, I added some custom entries to the /etc/grub.d/40_custom file in order to have control over where on the drive the OS will get booted. Additionally, following the comment by @Tom Yan, I replaced every set root=(x,y) and other stuff similar to it with instructions pointing to the UUID instead of anything other than that.
Regarding the creation of the custom entries I just copied the false entries from /boot/grub/grub.cfg to 40_custom and edited them. Here an example of kalis new entry:
menuentry 'Kali GNU/Linux Rolling (on portable SSD)' --class kali --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-aeb7f797-****-ba52f1738b>
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        search -u "aeb7f797-****-ba52f1738b2d" -s
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  aeb7f797-***-ba52f1738b2d
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid aeb7f797-****-ba52f1738b2d
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.6.15-amd64 root=UUID=aeb7f797-****-ba52f1738b2d ro quiet splash noautomount quiet splash zswap.enabled=1 zswap.zpool=z3fold zswap.compressor=lz4
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.6.15-amd64
}

